# pass variable into class in MVC pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am using the MVC pattern in PHP.
The MVC pattern limits you to calling methods within classes. 
As far as I understand I cannot work outside the scope of a class.

How then do I pass a variable into a function? the only place I found I can declare the variable is inside the function. This makes the function `static` and not re-usable!

Example:

```
class usersModel {
    function q(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname='eli'";
        $result1 = $this->conn->query($sql);
        $result2 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
        $fname = ($result2['fname']);
        return $fname;
    }
}
```

Onwards, when I create an object of the class in a different class:

```
$model = usersModel();
$result = $model->q();
```

Where would I declare the variable `$sql` so that I don't have to include it inside the function?

Comment: You pass arguments to a class method the same way as you would to a function. `public function q($sql) { ... }` and call it with: `$class->q('SELECT * FROM ....');`. I would recommend that you read up on using classes and PHP OOP in general.

Comment: Btw, `$model = usersModel();` is not how you create a new class instance. You need the `new` keyword: `$model = new usersModel();`

Comment: MVC doesn't _force_ you to do anything. It's just a way to structure your code if you want. How to split up the responsibilities. Also, I have no idea what you mean by your last comment. That makes no sense. _"It's just that I can only call the function from inside a class"_ - You can call a method from anywhere, as long as you have the class instance. This question shows that you haven't grasped how OOP really works so I would recommend doing some more research.

Comment: Dear Magnus, thank you for your response. Please be kinder as I am just learning. OOP I think I grasped quite well, it's MVC I am learning now. In MVC, you call a controller (class) and then you call a method (within that class). That's how it works. I don't believe you can call lone methods. Thus, if the variable is outside the class it isn't included in the method. Thus the function that I call cannot  continue.

Comment: The `$sql` variable should be in the function, BUT you probably want to pass in the value to use to match fname.  `$result = $model->q('eli');` and in your method have `function q( $fname ){` and you should use prepared statements to link the passed name to the query for the data.

Comment: _"Please be kinder"_ - In what way have I been unkind? Since MVC is only a way for you to split up the responsibilities in your code, it doesn't change how you work with classes and methods in general, so I'm simply pointing out that you probably don't know OOP as well as you think. Me suggesting you to read up on it is not to be rude, it's to be helpful. In all honesty, it can also be that the question is very unclear so I'm not actually getting what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare function public then you can access method outside the class and pass sql param to method.

```
 class usersModel {
    public function q($sql){ 
          $result1 = $this->conn->query($sql);
          $result2 = $result1->fetch_assoc(); 
          $fname = ($result2['fname']); 
          return $fname; 
     }

 }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname='eli'"; 

$user = new usersModel();
$user->q($sql);
```

Comment: No you don't. You _should_ declare it public for readability, but omitting the visibility will make the method public by default. Either way, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question in any way.

Comment: Dear Vishal, your response appears to be only the calling of the method. This does not address the question. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Vishal, you example would work if i call $user->q($sql) outside of a class. The problem is, MVC constrains you to work only within classes. This means I have to call this method inside another class. This means I am left without any place do declare $sql.

Comment: You can use the last three lines of code inside a class, too. I don't get your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone and thank you for your input!

This is the answer I was looking for -- I must delcare the variable as a constant outside the class in order for the method in the class to be able to reach it!

```
define("SQL","SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname='eli'");
class usersModel {
function q(){

    global $result1;
    $result1 = $this->conn->query(SQL);
    $result2 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
    $fname = ($result2['fname']);
    return $fname;
}
```